# Implement credit card payment using NFC (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, nfc, payment, credit-card, emv

I'm trying to implement a credit card payment using a flutter app (like Apple/Goggle pay).
The main goal is to store the relevant information about the credit card from a scan or from given details (whatever is possible) and later use it to make a payment with a payment terminal device.
An example is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aifXMV8PLYM, but unfortunately the source code of the mobile application has been removed.

Thanks,
Noy.

Comment: On Apple Pay or Google Pay, you see only scanning the card and later using it to tap and pay, but there is a lot happening behind the screen. Tokenization - in one word. You get a card personalized on the device, and this includes the security key which is used for the computation of cryptogram. You can never get this out using any type of reader. If you have used a mock terminal and captured all the details to try on a device, this won't work because the cryptogram is based on an unpredictable number generated by the terminal every time a transaction is performed.

Answer (score 3):

You are definitely able to read NFC-Tags (Credit-Cards) using Flutter. I have tested the nfc_manager package (https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager) successfully, with the provided example. Emulating does not seem to be supported by this package.

If you want to emulate NFC maybe checkout this package: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator

Answer (score 0):

You can read it, but obtaining your information such as your number, expiration date and cvv is not possible with that package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: illustrative]
*Illustration*

To clarify an important point, it's essential to understand that direct payments cannot be made through NFC (Near Field Communication) alone. The underlying technology that enables such transactions is known as contactless payment, which is a broader term than just NFC.

Contactless payment technology allows users to make payments by simply tapping their device near a payment terminal, utilizing NFC as a bridge, but the actual payment process involves more complex, secure protocols to ensure the transaction is safe and authenticated.

As of now, this advanced feature is not universally available and is supported only by select banks and financial institutions. If you're interested in finding out whether your bank supports this cutting-edge technology, you can explore the available options and get more detailed information on the official page [here](https://developer.apple.com/tap-to-pay/).

This information is particularly useful for consumers who are keen on leveraging the latest digital payment methods for their convenience and security.